# How to change the text of the sign in button on the top header of a magento store

Tags: localisation, menu, magento2.1.5, topmenu

I am currently developing my first Magento website and the whole functionality behind is overwhelming so I might have overseen the possibility to fulfill the task.

I am looking for a way to change the text of the top menu which can be seen on this page: http://sndev.calapo.at/

[image]

On the top right we can see two links "Sign In" and "Create an Account" I would like to rename those into "*Login*" and "*Register*" - how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv. check for line `"Sign In","Sign In"` replace with `"Sign In","your desired text"`

Comment: My app directory doesn't contain a locale folder oO

Comment: @noa-dev which magento version are you using.if it is magento 2 you can see it vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: yes it's Magento 2.1.5

Comment: can I just create a copy of the en_US.csv and rename it de_DE to have a german version of for the german store view?

Comment: @noa-dev yes do it