# Change the links in a custom third party theme

Tags: theme, toplinks

I have to change the text "Prijava" in the header to "Login". See the image:
[image]
How can I do this? I tried to look for it in the .phtml and Block class, but I couldn't find the text "Prijava" nowhere, in order to change it. Where can it be? I tried also to look at the CMS tab Static Blocks and Pages section in admin, but this text doesn't exist there either.

Comment: You could try this ... In an SSH session **grep -r "Prijava" .** from your installation directory

Comment: I get a warning: recursive search of stdin when I do that.

Comment: grep -r "Prijava" . gives me no results. Before I did it without the dot at the end, creating the recursion

Comment: I hope [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170924/how-to-change-the-text-of-the-sign-in-button-on-the-top-header-of-a-magento-stor/170941) will help you.

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase the question now. I don't need to only change the text but also the <a href tag to change the URL that the links are pointing to.

Comment: Closing the question and will open another one for the problem.

Comment: greping just the dump DB file solved the problem. @jscar please write an answer and I can accept it then. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find where the text is from an ssh session. Type `grep -r "Prijava"` from your installation directory.
The `-r` switch makes it recursive.